# Url Encoding with Multiple Query String Parameters

Tags: c#, url, html-encode

In my c# code I am encoding my Url that has multiple query strings. When at the receiver end I try to read back the query strings I get the null values (query string parameter is not found) reason being encoding changes &querystringparameter to &querystringparam. How to get around this.

```
Response.Redirect(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Add.aspx?ID=" + 1 + "&cid="+ 8 + "&jid=" +9));
```

On the add.aspx page i get the url as "add.aspx?id=1&sid=3&jid=9"

Comment: Can you give an explicit example of your URL before and after encoding and how you're encoding - you seem to explain that encoding is cutting off query string parameter names but it's hard to tell why with the information given.

Comment: How do you encode/decode query string?

Comment: Can you post an example with code what you do?

Comment: Based on your update there are plenty of issues here. First one to tackle is escaping certain characters, specifically the double quotes here since they're messing with your string and not concatenating as you expect.

Comment: lets make it more simple.please refer the change.

Answer (score 5):

Use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`, I bet it will work like a charm.
Read [this](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/urlEncoding/) article for more information.

Comment: you mean where I read the query string or instead of HttpUtility.HtmlEncode?

Comment: I have edited my answer, check out the link, it should be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest issue is that you're encoding the whole query string.  You need to encode the individual components, then concatenate them together.